# Explicit struct layout not assignable from an interface?

Tags: c#

In the following example why is isAssignable false?

```
public struct Bar
{
    public int A;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Foo<T> : IMyInterface
    where T : struct
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int A;

    [FieldOffset(4)]
    public T B;
}

public interface IMyInterface {}

...

var isAssignable = typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Foo<Bar>));
```

If I remove or change the layout type to LayoutType.Sequential, isAssignable is true.

Edit: Made it into a generic to further match my actual code.

Comment: Doesn't repro for me...copy/pasted your code and `isAssignable == true`

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your runtime environment?

Comment: internally, this will either call `RuntimeTypeHandle.CanCastTo`, which is unmanaged, or [ImplementInterface](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/type.cs,1718). Does typeof(Foo).GetInterfaces() contain IMyInterface?

Comment: Runtime environment is using C# 7 in Mono within Unity.

Comment: Does this even compile? I get "Could not load type 'Foo'1 from assembly '...' because generic types cannot have explicit layout".

Comment: It compiles within Unity, so it appears this might be an issue with their compiler not flagging it as unsupported and instead it is failing silently?

Comment: nm my previous comment... (palm to face)

Comment: Try testing it after your edit.  I don't believe you can use ```LayoutKind.Sequential``` with generic types.

Comment: The edited code causes an `ReflectionTypeLoadException` for me because generic types cannot have an explicit memory layout.